# How to put TODO faces in the file?

Tags: org-mode

I have defined the following TODO states in a org-mode file:

```
#+SEQ_TODO: TODO(t) WAIT(w) | DONE(d)
```

And I have customized the colors for the TODO states:

```
Hide Org Todo Keyword Faces:
INS DEL Cons-cell:
            Keyword: TODO
            Face   : Value Menu Color: red
INS DEL Cons-cell:
            Keyword: WAIT
            Face   : Value Menu Color: orange
INS DEL Cons-cell:
            Keyword: DONE
            Face   : Value Menu Color: green
INS
```

But I would like to customize the colors of the TODO states at the same place, where I have defined them: in the file.

How can this be done?

Comment: file local variables?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can add the following to the top of your `.org` file:

```
# -*- org-todo-keyword-faces: (("TODO" . "red") ("WAIT" . "orange") ("DONE" . "green")); -*-
```

The `-*- ... -*-` syntax is used to specify [File-Local Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html).

Comment: Yes of course. I did not thought about buffer variables. I was looking for something like this: `#+SEQ_TODO: TODO(t red) WAIT(w orange) | DONE(d green)`

Comment: @ceving Based on the documentation for `org-todo-keywords`, this doesn't seem to be possible. (To see for yourself, type `C-h v` `org-todo-keywords` `RET`).

Comment: Rather than using a cons-cell, it may be helpful to use the face properties; e.g., instead of the dot/period, use `:foreground"`.  And, perhaps consider adding a more complex example that sets both the background and foreground for a particular keyword.  This same concept of using a traditional list instead of a cons-cell also applies to `org-todo-priority-faces`.

Answer (score 8):

*I* can't make the "# -*-..." syntax work in my .org file (I can accept that I probably did something wrong. :-).

I got the following to work.  Place this at the bottom of your .org file:

```
# Local Variables:
# mode: org
# org-todo-keyword-faces: (("ANSWER" . "orange") ("ARCHIVED" . "blue") ("DATE" . "red") ("DOING" . "yellow") ("DONE" . "green") ("HPSM" . "red") ("JIRA" . "red") ("TODO" . org-warning) ("WAITING" . "orange"))
# End:
```

Comment: I successfully tested the `-*-` syntax using the interactive command `add-file-local-variable-prop-line`. I specified `org-todo-keyword-faces` for the variable and `(("TODO" . "purple"))` for the value. After calling `revert-buffer` things work as expected. The resulting line is `# -*- org-todo-keyword-faces: (("TODO" . "purple")); -*-`

Comment: Okay.  This works now.  I *SWEAR* I did this before and couldn't make it work.  Regardless, the -*- syntax works fine.

Comment: This is driving me nuts... The line by @glucas containing purple works, but this one with red `# -*- org-todo-keyword-faces: (("TODO" . "purple") ("IN-PROGRESS" . "red")); -*-` does NOT... Any hints?

Comment: @nephewtom Seems OK here. I copied your line to an org file, then re-opened the file and checked the value of `org-todo-keyword-faces`. Note that you would need to add IN-PROGRESS to `org-todo-keywords` as well.

Comment: Don't know what was happening... I may have confused myself. But it seems it happened to Bill too. Anyway, I finally got it working with this post too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707492/add-custom-markers-to-emacs-org-mode

Comment: I forgot that tyou have the `-*-` as the first line in the file, that's why it didn't work for me at first.