# How to customize DONE headlines per-file in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, faces, file-local-variables, local-variables

I would like to customize the headline and keyword inside of an `org` file. In [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/4104/how-to-put-todo-faces-in-the-file) is shown how to change the faces of each keyword, but not the headlines.

For the moment, I haven't achieve it and I don't have any idea what to do?

I have the 9.2 version of org-mode.

The header in my org file is:

```
#+TODO: TODO(t!) HIGHLIGHT(h!) WAIT(w@/!) | DONE(d!) CANCELED(c@)
```

And the footer is:

```
# Local Variables:
# org-fontify-done-headline: t
# org-todo-keyword-faces: (("TODO" . org-warning) 
#                          ("HIGHLIGHT" . (:foreground "yellow" :background "red" :weight bold)) 
#                          ("WAIT" . "yellow")
#                          ("CANCELED" . (:foreground "red" :background "white" :weight bold)) 
#                          ("DONE" . (:foreground "green" :strike-through t)))
# End:
```

PS: I can change the faces for the keywords `HIGHLIGHT`, `WAIT` and `CANCELED`. However, the `TODO` and `DONE` items keep unchanged.

Comment: I had to hack the code at several locations to have `org-mode` treat some file-local settings correctly, including making some variables buffer-local instead of global.  Due to the different versions of `org-mode` that people use, and due to the frequent changes in the master, it may be necessary to submit a bug report to the `org-mode` developers.  Before submitting a bug report, however, be sure to try out the latest version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using the version 9.2 and changed the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Set `org-fontify-done-headlines` to `t` and then `org-headline-done` face to the desired face

> Non-nil means change the face of a headline if it is marked DONE.
>   Normally, only the TODO/DONE keyword indicates the state of a headline.
>   When this is non-nil, the headline after the keyword is set to the
>   ‘org-headline-done’ as an additional indication.

However, this global not per-file.

Answer (score 0):

You can similarly customize the variable `org-level-faces`.

```
# org-level-faces: ((:foreground "yellow") (:foreground "red") )
```

This will customize the faces of org-level-1 org-level-2 ... by order.